# tidytext error (Error in is_corpus_df(corpus) : ncol(corpus) >= 2 is not TRUE)

Tags: r, tidytext

I am trying to do some basic text analysis.  After installing the 'tidytext' package, I tried to unnest my data frame, but I keep getting an error.  I assume there is some package I am missing, but I am not sure how to figure out which.  Any suggestions appreciated.

### #

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)


#Import data  
  text <- read.csv("TextSample.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  n= nrow(text)

  text_df <- tibble(line = 1:n, text = text)

   text_df %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

>
Error in is_corpus_df(corpus) : ncol(corpus) >= 2 is not TRUE

dput:

```
structure(list(line = 1:6, text = structure(list(text = c("furloughs", "Students do not have their books or needed materials ", "Working MORE for less pay", "None", "Caring for an immuno-compromised spouse", "being a mom, school teacher, researcher and professor" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of `text_df` by using `dput(head(text_df))`?

Comment: >    dput(head(text_df))
structure(list(line = 1:6, text = structure(list(text = c("furloughs", 
"Students do not have their books or needed materials ", "Working MORE for less pay", 
"None", "Caring for an immuno-compromised spouse", "being a mom, school teacher, researcher and professor"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column `text` is actually a dataframe within the dataframe `text_df`, so you are trying to apply `unnest_tokens()` to a dataframe, but it will only work if you apply it to an atomic vector (character, integer, double, logical, etc.).

To fix this, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

text_df <- text_df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Edit:

`dplyr` now has the `across` function, so `mutate_all` would be replaced with:

```
text_df <- text_df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.character(.))) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 186 x 2
   line  word     
   <chr> <chr>    
 1 1     c        
 2 1     furloughs
 3 1     students 
 4 1     do       
 5 1     not      
 6 1     have     
 7 1     their    
 8 1     books    
 9 1     or       
10 1     needed   
# ... with 176 more rows
```